# Wordpress Theme Got 502 proxy error -The proxy server could not handle the request GET /check

Tags: wordpress, validation, w3c-validation

I just finished create my own wordpress theme. But when I checked the html validation through validator.w3.com, it got:

502 Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /check.

Reason: Error reading from remote server.
Apache/2 Server at validator.w3.org Port 80

What does it mean? As far as I know, I don't play around using any proxy server.

----- EDIT: -----

Looks like the problem is in functions.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='admin-functions.php'){
**codes here***
}
```

If I remove the if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='admin-functions.php'), it returns no 502 proxy error. How should I fix this code to get through the w3 validator?

Many thanks!

----- EDIT: -----

oh well, apparently it's not the problem. Even if I remove the if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='admin-functions.php'), it sometimes returns 502 error, but sometimes not. I really don't get the idea.

-----FOUND THE SOLUTION!-----

call me stupid!

I found the problem:
I use these DOCTYPEs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

then I erased all of them and change to :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
I use these DOCTYPEs:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

then I erased all of them and change to :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Works fine now